# TikZ: Northeast Anchor?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In `TikZ`, I am trying to create a point with text in its northeast. I know that you are supposed to use something like `\node[anchor=northeast] {Whatever}`, but this just gives me an error. Here's my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw [blue] (0,0) circle(2pt) node[anchor=northeast] {Origin};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there some sort to TikZ library or something for that? Please let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`north east`, not `northeast`. Anchor names in TikZ have spaces.